# Start camera on button click in textureview

Tags: android

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView1);
    mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    }
 @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width,
        int height) {
        mCamera = Camera.open(0);

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mCamera.startPreview();


}

@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Currently when i run this program camera starts automatically. how can i start the camera on button click.i tried using a button in on click. but then there was no textureview available on the screen. Please suggest

Comment: refer https://github.com/dalinaum/TextureViewDemo/blob/master/src/kr/gdg/android/textureview/CameraActivity.java

Comment: i did that but when i run the application the space where textureview has to be dislayed is left blank and on clicking button it displayed. Can we show a black screen when the button is not clicked just like in surface view

Answer (score 0):

You should have both a button and a TextureView in your layout file like

Your camera is calling automatically because  `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` will be called as soon as your TextureView ready. So instead of calling Camera directory you can setup a button listener after your TextureView in ready inside `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` .

Here is the code snippet for the same.

inside **main_layout.xml**

```
  <TextureView
    android:id="@+id/ttv"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World" />
```

Now Inside `onCreate()` or `OnCreateView()` {in case of fragments}

Get both your `Button` and `TextureView` using `findViewById(...)`

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener{

   TextureView tv;
   Button b;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    tv = (TextureView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ttv);
    tv.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

    b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);

  }

   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        final SurfaceTexture surfaceT = surface;
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCamera = Camera.open(0);

                try {
                    mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceT);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

    }
 }
```

Don't Forget to add these Camera Permission and Feature in your manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```